# Django RedirectView.as_view not working

Tags: python, django

Below is the entry in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:

  url(r'^login/','juicy.views.login'),

  url(r'^mylogin/',RedirectView.as_view(permanent=False,url="http:\\www.google.com")),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

And this is my template.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action=\mylogin\ method = get>
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google">
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Problem is whenever i Click the button "Go to Google" it tries to open the url 
as

```
<code>
"http://localhost:8000/mylogin/%5Cwww.google.com". 
<code>
```

Funny thing is it was working till yesterday evening. I was able to go to google.com. After clearing the cache/cookie and some other cosmetic modifications I re-run the server and wooah back to square one.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"http:\\www.google.com"` is not the URL you have in mind. Try it with forward slashes: `"http://www.google.com"`.

More precisely, `"\\"` is being interpreted as a single escaped backslash, so your apparent URL is `"http:\www.google.com"`. Without the `//` marker to separate the scheme from the hostname, that looks like a relative URL which should be resolved relative to the current page - which is exactly what you're seeing.

Fully escaping the `"\\"` sequence (or using a raw string, which don't interpret escape sequences) would not solve your problem - `"http:\\www.google.com"` is also a relative URL. I mention this mostly to explain why you're only seeing a single `%5C` sequence in your resolved URL. `%5C` is the hex for a backslash character.

You also seem to have backslashes in your form action - that should be `<form action="/mylogin/" method="get">`.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Such a silly mistake.It worked now. Yesterday when it was working it must be with forward slash. Today when re-writing I used backward slashes. :)